# Change Ant Design Pro Table pagination language

Tags: ant-design-pro

I have already set the `ProTable`'s language to en-US. Everything is translated to English already but the pagination footer still is in Chinese. How can I change the pagination language to English?

[image]

```
import ProTable, { ProColumns, IntlProvider, enUSIntl } from '@ant-design/pro-table';

const ProTableList: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <IntlProvider value={enUSIntl}>
      <ProTable<TableListItem>
        headerTitle="Example List"
        actionRef={actionRef}
        rowKey="key"
        ...
      />
      ...
    </IntlProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use **Ant Design** with **Pro Components** than you need to use Internationalization from non pro version of Ant Design.

Wrap your **App** or in this case only **ProTable** component with **ConfigProvider** like in code below and you will get english translate.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import enUS from 'antd/lib/locale/en_US';
import ProTable from '@ant-design/pro-table'

const YourComponent = () => {
    return (
      <ConfigProvider locale={enUS}>
        <ProTable />
      </ConfigProvider>
    );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out but forgot to update the answer here. The `ProTable` component has a `showTotal` method under `pagination`. You can use the provided `total` and `range` variables to modify the displayed pagination text.

```
import ProTable, { ProColumns, IntlProvider, enUSIntl } from '@ant-design/pro-table';

const ProTableList: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <IntlProvider value={enUSIntl}>
      <ProTable<TableListItem>
        headerTitle="Example List"
        actionRef={actionRef}
        rowKey="key"
        ...
        pagination={{
          showTotal: (total, range) => (
            <div>{`showing ${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total} total items`}</div>
          ),
        }}
      />
      ...
    </IntlProvider>
  )
}
```

Will result in this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same issue, I think it's a bug. You can disable it by setting 
`showTotal` to `false`

```
pagination={{ showTotal: false }}
```